# How do I add a Go-To Action to an email using Gmail schema.org recs?

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail, schema.org, microdata, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to add a Go-To Action to an outgoing email using the following page as a guide:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/reference/go-to-action

In testing, the action is not showing up.  Here is the exact code I am using.  I have tried both the JSON-LD and microdata formats.

**JSON**

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "action": {
    "url": "http://www.barbaraboxer.com/petitions/MSA?sc=RB_msa",
    "name": "Sign Now"
  },
  "description": "Sign on as a citizen co-sponsor of the Military Justice Improvement Act"
}
</script>
```

**Microdata**

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EmailMessage">
  <div itemprop="action" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ViewAction">
    <link itemprop="url" href="http://www.barbaraboxer.com/petitions/MSA?sc=RB_msa"/>
    <link itemprop="name" href="Sign Now"/>
  </div>
  <meta itemprop="description" content="Sign on as a citizen co-sponsor of the Military Justice Improvement Act"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The markup seems correct, however, as you are not a whitelisted sender yet, you can only try it by sending emails to yourself. All emails with schema must also be signed with DKIM or SPF to prove that you are the actual sender. How are you sending emails? Easy ways to have them signed include using Gmail SMTP or App Engine.

Comment: We are using both DKIM and SPF to verify the identity of the sender.  We use Silverpop as our ESP.  Since posting this question, I was able to find a page that mentions registering with Google - https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/registering-with-google. However, there's no mention of that page in the Gmail Actions intro (https://developers.google.com/gmail/). Should I complete that process as described?

Comment: Registration is only required when you want to send emails with markup to everyone, if you are testing sending emails to yourself that doesn't require registration. Are sender and recipient of your test email the same address?

Comment: When you say "same address" do you mean the Envelope (SMTP) FROM/TO or the MIME headers From/To ? Does this work also for Google Apps accounts?

Comment: Envelope (SMTP) FROM/TO. Yes, it works for Google Apps accounts (as soon as it rolls out to them).

Comment: We would like to send this action to our newsletter list, so we have applied using the registration link above.

Comment: Thanks, we'll start processing those requests soon

Comment: @ClaudioCherubino Should emails sent via SMTP from oneself to oneself work without DKIM signatures? I've logged in using `openssl s_client -host smtp.gmail.com -port 587 -starttls smtp -crlf` and directly pasted a MIME email with `text/html` containing the `ViewAction` markup. Received email is not DKIM signed. The markup is the same as in Google-assembled and DKIM-signed email as scripted at http://script.google.com/. Yes - the latter has the signature; the prior does not. Recipient and sender are the same in both cases. Do you want me to open a new question to discuss this further?

Comment: Emails sent to yourself should be signed, otherwise there'd be no way for us to prevent spammers from spoofing your address and send you emails with schemas. If you need further details, please open a new question